# ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000 error while using WITH in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query :

```
WITH abc AS
(

   (SELECT SRC_DATA.*,
     (SELECT MAX(DECODE(OBJ.AUD_ACTION_FLAG,'D',OBJ.OUPDATE_COUNT,OBJ.NUPDATE_COUNT))
    FROM SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.AUD_TRIAL_DESIGN OBJ
    WHERE OBJ.AUD_DATE_CHANGED BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-1900') AND (SRC_DATA.AUD_DATE_CHANGED)
    AND DECODE(OBJ.AUD_ACTION_FLAG,'D',OBJ.OTRIAL_NO,OBJ.NTRIAL_NO)= DECODE(SRC_DATA.AUD_ACTION_FLAG,'D',SRC_DATA.OTRIAL_NO,SRC_DATA.NTRIAL_NO)
    AND OBJ.AUD_ACTION_FLAG <> 'D'
    ) UPDATE_COUNT,

 /***Multiple select statement like above with many other look up tables like  AUD_TRIAL_DESIGN ****/

FROM SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.AUD_TRIAL SRC_DATA  /***AUD_TRIAL  is the base table***/
),    


WITH def AS
(SELECT OBJ_DATA .*,
/***Similar statement as mentioned in above block and lookup table is AUD_OBJECTIVE***/

FROM SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.AUD_TRIAL_OBJECTIVE OBJ_DATA /***AUD_TRIAL_OBJECTIVE is the base table***/
)
```

----Query to select columns-----

```
FROM abc
LEFT JOIN def
LEFT JOIN xyz ON (column from def = column from xyz)
```

For the simliar structure of query written by me, following error is returned :

```
ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000
01792. 00000 -  "maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create a table or view with more than 1000
           columns, or to add more columns to a table or view which pushes
           it over the maximum allowable limit of 1000. Note that unused
           columns in the table are counted toward the 1000 column limit.
*Action:   If the error is a result of a CREATE command, then reduce the
           number of columns in the command and resubmit. If the error is
           a result of an ALTER TABLE command, then there are two options:
           1) If the table contained unused columns, remove them by executing
           ALTER TABLE DROP UNUSED COLUMNS before adding new columns;
           2) Reduce the number of columns in the command and resubmit.
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution

Comment: This error seems pretty self-explanatory: either your end result, or some intermediate in the query, exceeds 1000 columns.

Comment: Please format the code as it's difficult to read.

Comment: Do you really need all columns? It's best practice to specify the columns you want to select, rather than using `*`

Comment: @Tim .. Does this mean the issue is because of the data in tables or the query ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger .. Yes i need all the columns

Comment: @PoojaPatil - it isn't because of the data. The number of columns in `AUD_TRIAL` plus the number of 'multiple select statements' getting aggregates in subqueries exceeds 1000; or the number of columns in `AUD_TRIAL_OBJECTIVE` plus the number of subqueries for that CTE exceed 1000; or the total number of both of them when you join them together exceeds 1000. If you really need all of those columns (from the two base tables, more than the subqueries), then there is no workaround in plain SQL. What are you planning to do with the output of the query?

Answer (score 9):

We had a similar problem (Here is an excerpt from the SR):

Creating view generates ORA-01792 maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

We have a new application that has a view that contains 35 columns. However, when creating it, it errors out stating that there are over 1000 columns, which is false. I will attach the view definition

Here is what Oracle said (and it did fix the problem):

Bug 19893041 : ORA-01792 HAPPEN WHEN UPDATE TO 12.1.0.2

closed as dup of

Bug 19509982 : DISABLE FIX FOR RAISING ORA-1792 BY DEFAULT.

Solution:
SQL> alter system set "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF'; 
Or 
B. Apply patch 19509982 
(no conflicts found with the attached opatch)

That may be the same issue you're encountering.