# FIRST_VALUE() causing column limit error when there are only two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

This query works fine on one of our servers but causes this error on a different server: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

The query runs if we remove the first_value function

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    acc.ACC_MASTER_ACC_NBR,
    first_value(ACO_ACC_CONDITION_CD) over (partition by ACC_MASTER_ACC_NBR order by ACO_ID)
from ACCOUNT_CONDITIONS aco 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS acc ON aco.ACO_AAD_ID = acc.ACC_AAD_ID
WHERE ACO_ENABLED_IND = 'Y' 
AND ACO_ACC_CONDITION_CD IN ('DELQ')
```

What would cause this error when the query returns two columns?

Comment: seems similar to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655654/ora-01792-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view-is-1000-error-while-usin/38659827

Comment: See if this helps

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128621/understanding-ora-01792-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view-is-1000

Comment: Founded two resources that might help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128621/understanding-ora-01792-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view-is-1000 AND https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0647718